# jQuery.text() does a loop for matched elements?

Tags: jquery, performance, loops

What is the difference in both the both the codes below:

**First way:**

```
$("p").text("test");
```

**Another way:**

```
$("p").text(function(){
    return "test " + $(this).index();
});
```

**via .each loop:**

```
$("p").each(function(c, obj){
    $(obj).text("test");
});
```

I just want to know that **how they are different to each other in terms of performance**. Like last one is obviously doing a loop, but what about the first two ways to do this? Do they also make loop to change the text of the matched elements in DOM?

Please suggest, thanks in advance!

Comment: yes.. they does make a loop

Comment: yes all of them... in terms of speed it could be 1, 3 & 2 fastest to slowest - but the first one supports only a common text for all elements where as second and third support dynamic content

Comment: Thanks, but I am curious to know that why 3 is faster than 2, as you mentioned above?

Comment: Even I'm surprised by it... I found it after profiling it http://jsperf.com/jquery-text-vs-each-text

Comment: hummm, loved this tool jsperf.com. really thanking you very much for this

Comment: but this shows that **second way is fastest**.

Comment: nope! I also tested and the second way is slower.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think you should consider answering

Comment: No, no... I got it wrong. That says operations per second. So, doing `each loop` is faster than second way according to that test.

Answer (score 1):

All of them should be doing an iteration since there could be multiple elements in the element set and the value should be set to each one of them.

But these are 2 different categories, the first one sets a static text to all elements where as 2nd & 3rd can sets dynamic texts.

In terms of performance 1st will be fastest... then 3rd and closely followed by 2nd(though I don't know why, I thought second will be faster than 3rd)

See the http://jsperf.com/jquery-text-vs-each-text

Comment: thanks Arun, this really helped. Let's see some more opinions on it.

Comment: Perhaps the string concatenation in option 2 makes it slower than option 3 for large sets?

Comment: @TGH no.. I think it is the $(this).index() - because in the jspref both has string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

In all cases it applies the text to all matching elements. The selector may give back multiple elements, so it's a loop even for option 1. Option 2 and 3 offer some more flexibility if you need info about the current element in the "loop"

Comment: please give some idea about performance of each way... thanks!